# swiftで使える色選択のライブラリについて

Tags: swift, cocoapods

swiftで使えるcolorPickerのライブラリを探しています。
条件があり、
1. LandScapeで使える事
2. CocoaPodsに対応している事
です。Objective-Cのライブラリでも構いません。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、どうかご教示くださいませ。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はじめまして、[GitHub](https://github.com)をColor Picker Swiftで検索してみると、[ChromaColorPicker](https://github.com/joncardasis/ChromaColorPicker)というのが見つかりました。MITライセンスでCocoaPods対応のようです。
他にもGitHubを探せばたくさん見つかるので、合わないようであれば、より好みのものを探して見て下さい。

Comment: Googleとhttps://www.cocoacontrols.comで探していて、見つからないので諦めていました。有難うございました。